Getting _jsonparsefailure in Logstash for a valid JSON structure
I am facing a bit of a pickle in regards to the Logstash JSON filter.
Our Opensearch stack is receiving some logs already parsed in a JSON format from FluentBit producers. However some fields seem for some reason to be containing unparsed JSON structures.
Example :
Field as seen in Opensearch Discover
The fields contents parse fine when I put them though an online JSON parser.
Field contents in online JSON parser
So I've decided to try to add some additional parsing with Logstash. The fields contents parse fine when I put them through individually trough a JSON filter in my local Logstash instance which I use for testing purposes. (I put the fields contents through the JSON filter using STDIN).
input {

  stdin {codec => json}
 
}

 
filter {

    json { 
        source => "message" 
    }

}

output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}  

Here is the output :
[2024-06-18T07:17:36,620][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{"ip": "15.156.227.207"}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2024-06-18T11:20:59.203Z,
            "ip" => "15.156.227.207",
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "z500l"
}

However when I put everything in production on our Logstash consumers and the whole log entry goes through my code I will get a _jsonparsefailure.
Error parsing json {:source=>"[data][requestMetadata][clientAddress]", :raw=>[{"ip"=>"15.156.227.207"}], :exception=>java.lang.ClassCastException}

My code :
filter {

      if [data][requestMetadata][clientAddress] {
        json { 
          source => "[data][requestMetadata][clientAddress]" 
        }          
      }
}

I'd appreciate any help anyone can provide.
Many thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

What you have is not a "valid JSON structure". Looking at the "raw" part of the error message it appears to be a ruby hash, which suggests it has already been parsed. Show what the event looks like when displayed by the stdout+rubydebug output.

@Badger thanks for the info. I've added the output in my post.
